# How does Ricci flow distinguish $S^n$ and other manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, ricci-flow

I have read some basic content of Ricci flow. When the dimension is 3, I know the metric will not vanish, and there is a classify of singularity . But I don't know ,how the Ricci flow distinguish different manifold.

For example, how Ricci flow distinguish $S^3$ and $T^3$ ?